# sentence with an action after "to be interested" ==> in OR to + verb

Tags: meaning-in-context

I wonder what preposition (in OR to) I may use after interested when there is a  verb after. 
ie : I want to win this game. I'm interested ( in knowing / to know ) your secret weapon. 
Regards

Answer (score 1):

The standart preposition for "interest" is "in"

So in your example: I am interested in knowing more about your secret weapon.

[Look at Cambridge Dictionary:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/interested)

***Yes, I'd be very interested in knowing more about the services your firm offers.***